# Fedora: NVIDIA kernel module missing. Falling back to nouveau

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

This is a bug which I've found littered across very many forums, with a plethora of advice (none of which has worked for me).

So far, the things to try (in no order beyond discovery online):

- make sure the kernel is allowed to boot by either:

  - a.`sudo mokutil --import /etc/pki/akmods/certs/public_key.der` to import the key for secure boot

    - details: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/Secure%20Boot
  - or b. disabling secure boot in UEFI

    - check `mokutil --sb-state` or `dmesg | grep -E 'secure|nvidia'` to verify.
- disable windows fast boot (there's also a UEFI fast boot, if you don't know which is which try this suggestion last)
- Reinstall

  - `sudo dnf remove \*nvidia\*` to remove everything
  - `sudo dnf install akmod-nvidia` to reinstall
- `sudo akmods --force` to make sure things are being built for the current kernel

  - `uname -r` to verify the kernel matches the one you're running
- `cat /var/log/akmods/` to see if there's any clues in akmods
- `modinfo -F version nvidia` to verify driver is being loaded
- `lspci -v | grep "VGA controller"` to get the ID of your driver (eg "0a:00.0")

  - `lspci -k -s <pci ID of your GPU>` to get details on what kernels are being used by the driver
  - make sure your GPU works with the driver you're trying to use https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/495.44/README/supportedchips.html
- `cat /proc/cmdline` to check that your boot is good

  - should have details about blacklisting novaeau

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I got the message `NVIDIA kernel module missing. Falling back to nouveau` it was because I had installed the wrong NVIDIA drivers for my old graphics card.

In other words, to solve this I followed this guide [RPM Fusion - HowTo - NVIDIA](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA).

In a nutshell, this is what I did:

1.- Uninstalling the wrong NVIDIA drivers. In my specific case, I knew the specific dnf transactions which installed those recently and I rolled them back.

2.- Find the exact model of my NVIDIA card:

```
# lspci | grep -e VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

3.- Visit [NVIDIA Support chips](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/495.44/README/supportedchips.html) website and find which driver had support for my exact GPU model; 470xx in my case.

4.- Go back to the previous RPM Fusion HowTo guide and followed the steps for installing that driver.

5.- After the reboot, the message disappeared.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today after upgrade to fedora 39. Looking into the modules folder, nvidia module is there. Turns out nvidia module is not listed in `module.dep`. so to fix my issue, just run

```
$ sudo depmod
$ sudo dracut -f # perhaps this as well
```

I don't know why the upgrade process missed to regenerate dep for nvidia modules. I have zfs modules installed as well, which was regenerated in module.dep and works okay.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that my GPU is old and I needed to change to another version:

```
$ sudo dnf remove \*nvidia\*
$ sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-470xx akmod-nvidia-470xx
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I was having the same problem, tinkered a lot with many things and importing the secure boot key was the solution, after runing `sudo mokutil --import /etc/pki/akmods/certs/public_key.der`, rebooting and doing the proper steps on the MOK boot, it worked just fine, no problems... I can't really help you more than this I'm not knowledgeable enough to do so.